# Achieving coloured logs using Log4net

Tags: c#, selenium, log4net

Now Iam getting error "failed to find configuration section 'log4net' in the application's `.config` file". This is my code in `log4net.config` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
<configuration>
<configSections>
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
</configSections>
<root>
<level Value="Info"/>
<level Value="Error"/>
<appender-ref ref="ColoredFileAppender" />
</root>

<appender name="ColoredFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString"/>
<file value="C:\CL2.html" />
<encoding value="utf-8" />
<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
<appendToFile value="false" />
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
<conversionPattern value="%CC" />
<converter>
<name value="CC" />
<type value="Cluster2.ColoredMessageConverter" />
</converter>
<mapping>
<level value="Info" />
<foreColor value="Green" />
</mapping>
<mapping>
<level value="ERROR" />
<backColor value="Red, HighIntensity" />
</mapping>
</layout>
</appender>
</configuration>
</log4net>
```

I have included this statement in the assembly:

```cs
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

I have included this statement in my program:

```cs
protected void Application_start(Object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
}
```

I'm having no idea of what is the issue. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use custom pattern layout to achieve this, and then wire it up in your log4net.config file.
Your code would look like:

```
public class ColoredMessageConverter : PatternLayoutConverter
{

    protected override void Convert(TextWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        string color = "";
        switch (loggingEvent.Level.Name)
        {
            case "DEBUG":
                color = "green";
                break;
            case "WARN":
            case "INFO":
                color = "white";
                break;
            case "ERROR":
                color = "pink";
                break;
            case "FATAL":
                color = "red";
                break;
        }
        string logToRender = string.Format(" <p style='color:{0}'>{1}</p>", color, loggingEvent.RenderedMessage);
        //Add logToRender to file

        writer.Write(logToRender);
    }
}
```

In your log4net.config, wire this converter as given below. Replace the 'Your namespace' with the correct one.

```
<log4net>
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="ColoredFileAppender" />
</root>
<appender name="ColoredFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="c:\test.html" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%CC" />
    <converter>
      <name value="CC" />
      <type value="<<Your namespace>>.ColoredMessageConverter" />
    </converter>
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: Hi aquaraga..thanks for replying fast..but I am writing the log file as HTML.I am new to this log4net..Dont feel bad if I am asking a stupid question..Coloredconsoleappender means is it to display in command prompt??

Comment: Yes you're right. It displays it in the command prompt. But the custom appender you'd be writing should modify a HTML file.

Comment: Hi Aquaraga..this is the code I have written..

is it ok??while runnig it doesn't create a file..Before it was creating a log file..

Comment: <log4net>
   <appender name="fileLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender" >
    <file value="C:\Logs\Cluster2Log.html" />
    
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <appendToFile value="false" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="--" />
      <mapping>
      <level value="Info" />
      <foreColor value="Green" />
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
      <level value="ERROR" />
      <backColor value="Red, HighIntensity" />
      </mapping>
      </layout>
  </appender>
  </log4net>

Comment: You cannot use console appender to add stuff to a file. I just mentioned 'ColoredConsoleAppender' as a reference implementation.

Comment: thanks..so how can I call each one in my program??

Its needed because I may have to call so many times may be after each function..

Comment: Do I have to change anything in my log4net.config file after creating a class shown above??

Comment: I cant use the above code..Error showing does not implement inherited abstract member 'log4net.Appender.AppenderSkeleton.Append(log4net.Core.LoggingEvent)'

Comment: Thanks..Let me check that...In between can you help me on how we can create a new line entry in html log file creation..??I am able to create a log file in html..but its showing like this..

2013-04-29 09:00:39,141 INFO [8] Cluster2.Class1.Test - Browsing Webpage *2013-04-29 09:00:40,190 ERROR [8] Cluster2.Class1.Test - Browing Failed, Exception*

I want to get the line marked in * in next line..not in continuation..In notepad it comes in next line..But not in html..

Help would be really appreciated...

Comment: 'using log4net.Layout.Pattern;' - will help. PatternLayoutConverter helps us to make finer changes to the message format of the log statements - like adding line numbers to log files, suppressing passwords from log statements, adding colors to log statements, etc.

Comment: Hi Aquaraga..Thanks..now the colour is coming..but may i ask u one more doubt..Iam getting the log in html,as i z before.in color it is coming like this..

[ 

Browsing Webpage

][ 

Browing Failed, Exception

]OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException

How can i make aligned in a neat way??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29088/discussion-between-vysakh-and-aquaraga)

Comment: Hi Aquaraga...One more issue after changing into colored logs as u said yesterday..I though you will be the correct person to clear that too..Please see my edited question above..

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what above is suggested, here is the code to add date/level/method along with that information

```
public class LoggerColoredMessageConverter : PatternLayoutConverter
{
    protected override void Convert(TextWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        string color = "";
        switch (loggingEvent.Level.Name)
        {
            case "DEBUG":
                color = "#383d41";
                break;
            case "WARN":
                color = "#856404";
                break;
            case "INFO":
                color = "#0c5460;";
                break;
            case "ERROR":
            case "FATAL":
                color = "#721c24";
                break;
        }
        string logToRender = string.Format(" <p style='color:{0}'>{1} {2} {3}" +
                                           " - {4}</p>", color, loggingEvent.TimeStamp, loggingEvent.Level.Name, 
            loggingEvent.LoggerName,
            loggingEvent.RenderedMessage);
        //Add logToRender to file

        writer.Write(logToRender);
    }
}
```

to log it like this:

11/15/2019 1:57:16 PM ERROR ASP.demo_aspx - My Error